# Jupyter notebook installation fail using pip3

Tags: pip, raspberry-pi-os

I've just setup a Raspberry Pi 3B+ with the latest Raspberry Pi OS image (all tools).  I'm trying to install Jupyter on it using the command 'sudo pip3 install jupyter' and I get the following errors;

Error: notebook 6.0.3 has requirement jupyter-core>=4.6.1, but you'll have jupyter-core 4.4.0 which is incompatiable.

Error: jupyter-client 6.1.3 has requirement jupyter-core>=4.6.0, but you'll have jupyter-core 4.4.0 which is incompatiable.

My version of pip3 is 20.1.1. 
The Raspberry Pi OS is; 
Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit) with desktop and recommended software
Image with desktop and recommended software based on Debian Buster
Version:May 2020
Release date:2020-05-27
Kernel version:4.19

Please could someone let me know how I can fix these?

Kind regards.

Alex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `--upgrade` which should upgrade the dependencies too:

```
sudo pip3 install jupyter --upgrade
```

If that doesn't work, I'd try upgrading jupyter-core first:

```
sudo pip3 install jupyter-core --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Pip is not always the best choice on RPi. I've had a few failures esp. where dependencies are concerned. I suggest you uninstall you're current Jupyter installation, and install Jupyter from the the Raspberry Menu -> Preference -> Add/Remove Software, Jupyter can be found as version jupyter-4.4.0-2.

I'm fairly sure that will do the trick since I have Jupyter running on one of my Pi3s quite nicely